# Requirement of の in this sentence?

Tags: particle-の, nouns, nominalization

I have come across this sentence:

> 毎日同じ**物**を食べる**の**は、面白くない

And I'm unclear as to why the の particle is required here since the noun has been established using 物; is it okay to omit the の in this case or would that grammatically invalidate the sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that in this sentence, what is uninteresting is not the `物` but the fact that you eat the same thing everyday.

Thus, you can "nominalize" the verb into `食べるの`.

After that, it's simply a matter of 「は」indicating the subject. You can thus parenthesize the phrase as :

`「毎日同じ物を食べるの」は面白くない`

Note that this is similar, albeit with a different nuance to `食べることは` where `こと` has the same function as `の`.

Comment: I've read another topic about when adding の after the verb it turns it into the gerund. I've understood this part however what would it mean to just have は after the verb and no の? 毎日同じ物を食べるは面白くない. What is the meaning now? I saw another answer which said you cannot put が after the verb because it must take a noun however it didn't say anything about は so I'm really curious now.